# In Alexa lambda javascript code, how can I get the name of the current account?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

In my home there are two Alexa accounts. I can ask Alexa "What account is this?" and it will give me the first name of the owner of the current account.  How can I get this information from within javascript Lambda code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you could always have Alexa ask :) or you could request customer contact info from the user: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html

You could also get the unique userId for the user currently interacting with the skill:

```
session.user.userId
```

Comment: I'm considering the case where the device is associated with 2 or more userIds, and I want to make sure that the person using the skill is the correct person.  So say there are two people, Alice and Bob.  When Alice invokes the skill, I want Alexa to ask if she is the holder of the current account.  I can't just give her the userid of that account, because it won't make sense to her.  I want to tell her the name of the holder of the current account so if it is Bob, she can switch accounts.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Ironically I gave you the right code but wrong description. session.user.userId will give you the unique ID of the current user so you can use that value to identify who's using the skill like you want.

Comment: Won't that give me the unique ID of the current account?  So if the current account is Bob's and Alice is invoking the skill, she will be providing data for the wrong account.  Since Alexa knows what the current account is, I should be able to access that information in the Lambda code, no?

Comment: You're right. If Bob's profile is active and Alice invokes the skill she'll be providing Bob's unique Id. I did some digging and it looks like what you're looking for is voice recognition so the skill knows who's invoking it. That's currently underway it seems and isn't available for public release just yet: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/09acb84e-6d56-463b-959c-9e15c3ed3893/announcing-more-personalized-skill-responses-when-alexa-recognizes-a-customer-s-voice-developer-preview. Hopefully this is released soon because I'd like to give it a whirl.

Comment: That's a good idea but unfortunately I need a workable solution for a skill I am developing right now.

Comment: Based on what I know, if I were to implement a skill like you're describing I would require the user to provide a code of sorts like a 4 digit pin. You can store that pin and any settings you wanted associated in dynamo. If the user doesn't have a pin they're required to "sign up" and create a pin. To handle the "owner" scenario you get an initial launch event the first time you launch the skill so I would set whichever account is first as the owner. You could always add another intent to change ownership if you wanted too. That's what I would do anyways :)